# Parsing html breaks javascript-related items although scripts are preserved

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So, I have a script that takes the innerHTML of body (yes, all the stuff in the body tag), converts all the Arabic numerals (123) into Arabic-Indic numerals (١٢٣), and replaces the innerHTML with the altered one. Now, the parser works perfectly, and only changes numbers that will be visible on the page for the user and avoids numbers in tag attributes, and leaves stuff inside 'sensitive' tags (like script, style, noscript...) unaltered (with a few kinks that I'm working out), just like I want it to! (this is running in a chrome extension by the way, and the script runs when the onLoad event is triggered)

But for some reason some things stop functioning as they should. For example, take a random question on stack overflow; the up/down-vote buttons stop working. I even went ahead and compared the original and unparsed htmls:

http://www.diffchecker.com/gJE1v50f

Everything looks okay there; the only differences are the numbers, although some links that are visible to the user (e.g. one in the formatting help part) are altered, but I plan to fix that, and it has no effect on the scripts anyway so I'm ignoring them for now.

Thanks for taking the time to read, an even greater amount of thanks for an answer :)

Comment: You say that the javascript breaks. Any error messages? My only guess is that the javascript somehow relies on seeing the other format of numerals in the HTML.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I don't get error messages :/ I also checked the script tags with just a source, and the source is unaltered and leads to the correct source. Your guess might be true though!
EDIT: I'm not really saying the javascript breaks, I'm just saying _something_ breaks. Guess I should have phrased that better, my bad.

Comment: If there are any events bound to elements via javascript (instead of inline), they will be removed because when you set innerHTML, it destroys the current DOM nodes and replaces them with new ones.

Comment: Oh my God this is going to be such a pain...this explains so much...thanks! You should post this as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: Instead of using innerHTML, you should be able to alter the text nodes.

Comment: Well, it gets extremely complicated, and just manually checking characters was way easier.

"Not today!" said fate.

Comment: Also, a quick test of replacing the upvotes text node for this question (with an arabic-indic numeral) shows it breaks the up voting script. The script apparently parses out and increments the number.

Comment: Oh, okay...
I'm screwed xD
Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: don't give up yet! neither of those problems are too terribly difficult to work around :)

Comment: True! I just felt annoyed that a whole 2 weeks' effort has gone to waste, that's all. If you count in the fact that I'm a first-year computer engineering major that's learning javascript and html as he goes, it's kind of a pain in the everywhere for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, replacing the html in the body of the page causes all new (though identical to the original) elements to be produced, which causes all the events attached to them to be discarded. What you want to do is loop through all the text nodes in the body. This is easiest to do using xpaths:

```
xpath = new XPathEvaluator()
xpath.evaluate("//text()", document.body)
```

This returns an array of all the text nodes in the body of the current document. You can then loop through them and modify each of their contents.

The other problem is that this may still break scripts that parse numbers out of the text nodes that you are modifying. The only solution I can think of for this (yes, it is very hackish) is to extend the behavior of the `Number` function:

```
(function (){
  var oldNumber = Number
  window.Number = function(obj){
    if(typeof obj == "string"){
      // replace numerals
      var numerals = ["٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩"]
      for(idx in numerals){
        obj = obj.replace(new RegExp(numerals[idx],"g"), idx)
      }
      // replace decimal point
      obj.replace(/٫/g,".")
    }
    return oldNumber(obj)
  }
})()
```

You would also have to extend the parseInt and parseFloat functions to get everything working, though the code will be almost identical. This would keep scripts that parse numbers out of the html from breaking; but note that when they display the numbers back onto the webpage, they will be normal arabic numerals. To work around this, you could extend Number's `toString` method, but this might be more dangerous than extending the number parsing functions, which were relatively safe.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question: when I should I run the function that overrides Number?

Comment: The function is anonymous, and gets called as soon as it is defined (that's what the `()` at the end is). That outer wrapper is only there to prevent the `oldNumber` variable from leaking out.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting the text nodes and modifying them directly: http://jsfiddle.net/6pLeR/

```
// this will get all text nodes that are descendant of element. 
function getTextNodes(element) {
    var nodes = [],
        children = element.childNodes,
        i=0, child = children[0];

    for (; i < children.length; i++, child=children[i]) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) nodes.push(child);
        else nodes = nodes.concat(getTextNodes(child));
    }

    return nodes;
}

var nodes = getTextNodes(document.body); // get all text nodes in the body.

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];

    node.data = node.data.replace(/text/g, "banana"); // replace "text" with "banana"
}​
```

You can see in the demo that the click event is unaffected by the change in the data of the node.